# How to create a continuously running socket client in python

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I have been using TCP socket for a while now in python and my socket client closes after sending a message but I want to create a **continuously running** socket client that will keep sending messages as I already have a **continuously running** listener server. So the socket client code which I like to work on is below:

```
import socket

TCP_IP = "0.0.0.0"
TCP_PORT = 5003

BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

array = [0, 5, 10, 15]
print("Sending sensor value",array)

MESSAGE = bytearray(array)  # converting to bytearray for sending via socket

# Sending via socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP,TCP_PORT))
s.send(MESSAGE)
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
s.close()
```

please advise

Comment: Have you tried putting `s.send` and `s.recv` into a loop?

Comment: `while some_condition_exists: ...` ?

Comment: Did you see the examples at the end of the [socket documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html)??

Comment: There are quite a few questions and answers on SO searching with your question. Do any of them answer your question? If so, let us know and we will mark yours as a duplicate.

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes I did. it workes but after some time my Linux freezes. That is why I was looking for all possible ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import socket
import time

TCP_IP = "0.0.0.0"
TCP_PORT = 5003

BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

array = [0, 5, 10, 15]


MESSAGE = bytearray(array)  # converting to bytearray for sending via socket

# Sending via socket
while True:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((TCP_IP,TCP_PORT))
    s.send(MESSAGE)
    data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    print("Sending sensor value",array)
    time.sleep(3)
    s.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually, I tried it just now and it is working. Didn't put any delay though before